# Acessing values from preg_match_all in PHP 7.4

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am trying to access the values from the results of preg_match_all.
Below is my coding:

```
$strNbrOfPages = preg_match_all($strPattern,$strWorkDetails,$matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Below is the results of ensuring there are values:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => PAGE [1] => 465 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => PAGE [1] => 5400 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => PAGE [1] => 10434 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => PAGE [1] => 15684 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => PAGE [1] => 20775 ) ) )
```

This my attempt to access the page location, i.e. 465,5400 etc.. I have tried various ways and (3 indices and 4 indices).I always end up with an error message - Array to string conversion error. What a I doing wrong??

```
echo '<BR>FROM $MATCHES: ' . $matches[0],[0],[1];
echo '<BR>FROM $MATCHES: ' . $matches[0],[1],[1];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the commas from your notation:

```
echo '<BR>FROM $MATCHES: ' . $matches[0][0][1];
echo '<BR>FROM $MATCHES: ' . $matches[0][1][1];
```

Comment: Thank you for responding!  I just discovered my error! And was pasting my correction.